# Why is my custom domain redirecting to the login page after successful login, where as my default cloudfront domain redirects to the application?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, custom-domain

I have a cloudfront distribution which has a default domain. When I login to my application with that it redirects to the application dashboard but when I login with my custom domain it redirects to the login page again. Any idea?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any solution ?

Comment: Hi can you show me how you have configured your custom domain. Actually I don't remember how I solved this as it's been quite some time now.

Comment: I fixed this issue.  Can you explain more about the error?  My application is now 100% working with cloudfront

Comment: ok sounds great ! let me know if you need any help